# Icon not aligning in the center of FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, floating-action-button

I am designing this activity for my Music Player App. I have three Floating Action Buttons to perform the ***Play***, ***Next*** and ***Previous*** actions.

[image]

However, I want the Next and Previous buttons to be slightly smaller then the Play button. To do this I adjusted the height and width of both buttons in this activity's xml file.

```
<!-- Prev. Button -->
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:id="@+id/id_prev"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/play_pause"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_previous"/>    

<!-- Play. Button -->
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/play_pause"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_play"/>

<!-- Next. Button -->
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/id_next"
    android:layout_width="45dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="22dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/play_pause"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_next" />
```

The problem I am facing is that every time I change the height and width of the floating action buttons to 45dp or any other size, the icons inside the buttons get pushed down to the bottom-right corner. This next image shows what I'm talking about.

[image]

How do I get the ***Next*** and ***Prev*** icons inside the floating action buttons to stay perfectly in the center and still maintain the size of both buttons at 45dp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add **`fabSize="mini"`** attribute instead of setting 45dp to `layout_width` and `layout_height` other than `wrap_content`.

```
<!-- Prev. Button -->
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/id_prev"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/play_pause"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_skip_previous"
    app:fabSize="mini" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use scale property instead...

`android:scaleX="0.9"`

`android:scaleY="0.9"`

Or in java....

Use `setScaleX` and `setScaleY` attributes...

Comment: This also produced the results I wanted, thank you for sharing this answer.